# How to solve the equation $x^2y-y^2 = e^ax^2+x^2$ in terms of $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Please help me solve the following equation in terms of $x$, I have difficulty with this:
$$x^2y-y^2 = e^ax^2+x^2$$

Edit with my solution:

Rewrite the equation
$$0 = y^2 - x^2y + (e^a+1)x^2$$
Using the quadratic formula we obtain
$$y = \frac{x^2±\sqrt{x^4-4(e^a+1)x^2}}{2}$$
and simplify we obtain
$$y = \frac{x^2}{2} \pm \frac{x\sqrt{x^2-4e^a-4}}{2}$$

Comment: Do you know how to solve a quadratic equation e.g. $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$?  This is one in disguise.

Comment: yes @badjohn      ...

Comment: what is $c$? Is it $-e^ax^2-x^2$? @badjohn

Comment: Almost. The $x^2$ term has a negative as well. Or they could both be positive if you brought the $y^2$ to their side. But you've got the right idea. Edit: I guess you caught the error and edited it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your equation as 
$$y^2 - (x^2)y + (e^ax^2+x^2) = y^2 -by +c$$
where $b$ and $c$ correspond to the terms in brackets. Then apply the standard technique to solve a quadratic equation.

Comment: use quadratic formula? @mlc

Comment: @mathweconway: yes, $y = (-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta})/2a$.

Comment: Can you verify my answer? I will finalize your answer

Comment: @mathweconway: You failed to square $e^a$. I am editing your answer (it's faster than typing it in a comment).